# Vector convolution?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-transform, vector-spaces, convolution

I am working on a research problem which leads to the following optimization problem:
\begin{equation}
\hat{M} = \operatorname*{arg\,max}_M \Bigl\lVert\sum_{k=0}^{M-1} {\mathbf y}_k \exp\left(-j 2\pi k \omega\right)\Bigr\rVert^2 \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}
where ${\mathbf y}_k$ is a complex vector and a function of the integer $k$, $\omega$ is a  real scalar (it does not change the problem if you assume that $\omega$ is some known number, say $1$), and $M$ is an integer scalar.

The problem that I have is using discrete convolution formula, i.e., $$z[n] = x[n]\star h[n] \triangleq  \sum_{k=0}^\infty x[k]h[n-k]$$ to rewrite the term $\|\sum_{k=0}^{M-1} {\mathbf y}_k \exp\left(-j 2\pi k \omega\right)\|^2$ as the norm of convolution of two functions.

If ${\mathbf y}_k$ was a scalar, i.e. $y_k$, the problem would be very straightforward. We could simply use
$$\sum_{k=0}^{M-1} {y}_k \exp\left(-j 2\pi k \omega\right) = y[n]u[n]\star \exp\left(-j 2\pi n \omega\right)u[n-M+1] $$ at $n=0$, where $u[n]$ is the discrete unit step function. My question is as follows: Is there a technique to use the convolution notation to rewrite \eqref{1}?

Comment: You want thr value of $M$ that maximizes this expression? But for different values of $M$ you must be using different sequences of vectors ${\bf y}_k$, and you haven't told us anything about how these different values are related. Are the ${\bf y}_k$ found by sampling the values of some continuous function on the unit circle, maybe?

Comment: I mean the answer to the specific question you asked is yes, you can just use the ordinary convolution formula by applying it coordinatewise.

Comment: Also on math.se: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372833/vector-convolution

Comment: @nikWeaver Exactly. It gives a good understanding of a possible solution of the optimization problem

Comment: @NikWaver, exactly. I'm looking for any new idea to tackle the optimization problem.